Will missing the Google Billing API v6 update deadline block all future app updates on Google Play?
Google Play requires me to update my app's Google Billing API from v5 to v6 before Nov 1. The message from the Play Console states that if I don't upgrade by this deadline, I won't be able to publish updates to the app. However, it’s unclear if updating to API v6 or newer after Nov 1 will restore the ability to update the app.
If I miss the Nov 1 deadline, will updating to Billing API v6 or newer still allow me to publish updates afterward, or is Nov 1 a strict cutoff that permanently blocks further updates if the requirement isn't met in time?
Additional Context: I am actively working on the update but won’t be able to meet the Nov 1 deadline due to the time needed for testing and finalization. I plan to publish the update in approximately six weeks, including all the latest libraries. I have already requested and received an extension from the original August deadline to Nov 1, but, unfortunately, I still won’t be able to meet this revised deadline.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic/272167

Yes, you can update the app after November 1 with v6. November 1 deadline is for v5. After November 1 you won't be able to update the app if it's using v5. After November 1, You must update to v6 in order to publish/update your app on Google Play
Google Play Billing Library version deprecation

Google Play Console's red warning triangles make it seem more severe than it is. Since this is a recommendation rather than a requirement, it would be more appropriate to show it as a yellow warning instead of making developers worry about potential app removal. Given that this will only effect future uploads.

@VidarVestnes Since they refuse to publish new apps/update existing ones after November 1 if not using v6, it can be considered a requirement. This involves restriction to publishing/update itself which is a core feature, maybe that's why it's a red warning. Imagine someone missing the yellow warning and trying to publish a critical update with v5
